# geom_density creates flat line with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to plot density lines with boxplots, but I just get a flat line that does not resemble the data distribution. What did I miss?

```r
library(tidyverse)
as_tibble(iris) %>%
  pivot_longer(!Species, names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Value, Measure)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_boxplot(width = .25, position = position_nudge(y = -.15), outlier.shape = NA) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, strip.position = "right", nrow = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could use `geom_density_ridges` from [ggridges](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html), which calculates the density from the provided data en then plots it like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)
as_tibble(iris) %>%
  pivot_longer(!Species, names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Value, Measure)) +
  geom_density_ridges() +
  geom_boxplot(width = .25, position = position_nudge(y = -.15), outlier.shape = NA) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, strip.position = "right", nrow = 3)  
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.0883
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.152
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.166
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

`geom_density` is useful to show a smoothed histogram.

Comment: Yes, I also tried that, but the data distribution looks different when comparing it to the distribution that ```geom_violin``` is showing. Also, the tails have to be cut with ```rel_min_height = .02```. I think there is a difference in how they are calculated.

Comment: Initially, I tried to use half violin, but every method gave flat lines or an error. I think it has something to do with the horizontal orientation:
```gghalves::geom_half_violin```, ```see::geom_violinhalf()```, ```PupillometryR::geom_flat_violin()```, ```sdamr::geom_flat_violin()```